# Bolding a string using NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

Im using the following code to bold a part of  string. I want only the `Shipment Ref. #:` to be bolded. Following is my code

```
  UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    NSString *yourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Shipment Ref. #: %@ ",[[[NSUserDefaults alloc] init] valueForKey:@"shipRef"]];
    NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(10, 4);

    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];

    [attrString beginEditing];
    [attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                       value:boldFont
                       range:boldedRange];

    [attrString endEditing];
    self.shipRefHeader.text = [attrString mutableString];
```

The problem is that it is not getting bolded

Comment: `self.shipRefHeader.text = [attrString mutableString];` => `self.shipRefHeader.attributedText = attrString;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

```
    NSString * yourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Shipment Ref. #: %@ ",[[[NSUserDefaults alloc] init] valueForKey:@"shipRef"]];;
    NSMutableAttributedString * attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];
    NSString *boldString = @"Shipment Ref. #:";
    NSRange boldRange = [yourString rangeOfString:boldString];
    [attrString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] range:boldRange];
    [self.shipRefHeader setAttributedText: attrString];
```

Comment: I didn't check the whole code of the author, but if I'm write, it's only error was that he/she was setting the text property instead of the attributedText one. Your answer doesn't point at all that mistake, you don't give any justification or explanation.